# Get Google Analytic View Id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

I have JavaScript function to return list of google analytics account names for a given email address. I want to get view Id by giving account name or account Id.Is there any API or way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering using [Account Summaries](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries) instead. It should give you a list of all accounts/properties/views. I think it will work better for you use case.

There is also a javascript example for calling it [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list#examples).

Answer (score 1):

I know that there aren't many JavaScript examples in these but have you tried checking out the official [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analytics/v3/) and [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/)? It makes things so much easier when you can go off of the given options and then convert them to JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you and But I couldn't able to find out a way to return view Id.

Comment: I bet there is a way with the "fields" settings, just find the right one or just be lazy like me and choose all of them :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) like you said we can get view Id from analytics.management.profiles.list API by giving items/Id for fields parameter.